# What does the declaration BufferData Data[16] = {0} mean

Tags: c, initialization

I am going through a C dll and came across a structure

```
BufferData{int Len; int Ant; unsigned char Data[512]}
```

the structure is then initialized by creating an array

```
BufferData Data[16] = {0}
```

I am uncertain what this does given that Data is an array of Structures.

Comment: It's creating an array `Data` of 16 elements and setting everything to 0. So for each element, every member will now be 0.

Comment: BufferData Data[16] = {{0}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quirk of C initializers. C has no "half initialized" variables; a variable is either uninitialized or fully initialized.

If an initializer specifies fewer values than the structure or array has members, all remaining elements are recursively implicitly initialized to zero.

Thus `{0}` is a universal initializer: It sets the first field (whatever that may be) to `0` and all remaining fields (if any) are automatically set to `0`, too.

In your case the first field is the first member of the first element of `Data`, i.e. we're explicitly setting `Data[0].Len` and relying on zero initialization for everything else.